# Correct use of Past perfect in this sentence

Tags: tenses

Is it correct to say as shown?

> "The thieves were running with the money they had stolen from the bank."

Comment: Yes, 'the stealing of the money' is anterior to 'the running', so the past perfect is correct here.

Comment: Though 'running off' or 'escaping' would sound more natural without further context.